# NOT NULL en MYSQL no funciona

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo una duda muy sencilla. Tengo una tabla usuarios como se ve en la foto, aunque todos los campos tienen restricción NOT NULL, al almacenar los registros me permite ingresar con algunos campos vacíos, siendo que tienen la restricción NOT NULL. ¿Se supone que no me debería dejar ingresar ningún dato en esos registros?. ¿Cómo hago para que si se cumpla el NOT NULL y no deje ingresar datos allí? Gracias.

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(  
id          int(255) auto_increment not null,     
nombre      varchar(100) not null,
apellidos   varchar(100) not null, 
email       varchar(255) not null,
password    varchar(255) not null,
fecha       date not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT uq_email UNIQUE (email)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

```
mysql> use blog_master;
Database changed
mysql> select * from usuarios;
+----+--------+-----------+----------------------+----------+------------+
| id | nombre | apellidos | email                | password | fecha      |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Moises | Quintana  | eduardo599@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-27 |
|  2 | Pedro  | Ramirez   | eduardo600@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-28 |
|  3 | Raul   | Rodriguez | eduardo601@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-29 |
|  4 | Moises | Baena     | eduardo602@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-30 |
| 25 |        |           |                      | admin4   | 0000-00-00 |
| 26 |        |           | admin@gmail.com      | admin    | 0000-00-00 |
| 28 |        |           | edu@gmail.com        |          | 0000-00-00 |
| 29 |        |           | edu1@gmail.com       |          | 2020-11-03 |
| 30 |        |           | edu2@gmail.com       | admin4   | 2020-11-03 |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------------+----------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc usuarios;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default   | Extra             |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------------------+
| id        | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment    |
| nombre    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL      |                   |
| apellidos | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL      |                   |
| email     | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL      |                   |
| password  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL      |                   |
| fecha     | date         | NO   |     | curdate() | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos) VALUES ('', '');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'uq_email'
mysql> INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos, email) VALUES ('', '', 'carlos@gmail.com');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from usuarios;
+----+--------+-----------+----------------------+----------+------------+
| id | nombre | apellidos | email                | password | fecha      |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Moises | Quintana  | eduardo599@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-27 |
|  2 | Pedro  | Ramirez   | eduardo600@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-28 |
|  3 | Raul   | Rodriguez | eduardo601@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-29 |
|  4 | Moises | Baena     | eduardo602@gmail.com | 1234     | 2020-10-30 |
| 25 |        |           |                      | admin4   | 0000-00-00 |
| 26 |        |           | admin@gmail.com      | admin    | 0000-00-00 |
| 28 |        |           | edu@gmail.com        |          | 0000-00-00 |
| 29 |        |           | edu1@gmail.com       |          | 2020-11-03 |
| 30 |        |           | edu2@gmail.com       | admin4   | 2020-11-03 |
| 32 |        |           | carlos@gmail.com     |          | 2020-11-04 |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------------+----------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Los códigos van como texto por favor

Comment: Hola, una caso es el null y otro el vacio, como tal vacio no es null y por eso te lo deja insertar

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agrega el insert que intentaste...

Comment: Gracias por responder Edgar Vazquez, totalmente de acuerdo, luego, ¿Cómo debo declarar el campo o que debo colocar para no deje llenar ningún nuevo registro si todos los campos no están llenos con datos?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana ya estas hablando de validar tal vez por ejemplo la longitud que sea mayor a 0, por ahi puedes empezar para que si la longitud del registro es mayor a 0 permita el insert y en caso contrario no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola podrias poner unas CHECK constraint para evitar eso , prueba con esto y me dices

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
id int(255) auto_increment not null,
nombre varchar(100) not null CHECK (nombre <> ''), 
apellidos varchar(100) not null CHECK (apellidos <> ''), 
email varchar(255) not null, 
password varchar(255) not null, 
fecha date not null, 
CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY(id), 
CONSTRAINT uq_email UNIQUE (email) )ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Puesto que me dices que no te funciona otra alternativa seria crear un disparador que cada vez que insertes lea ese dato para verificarlo, en el ejemplo que te pondré solo seria con un campo tu agregarías los que necesites, la idea es mostrarte como funciona

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE INSERT ON usuarios
FOR  each ROW
BEGIN
if new.nombre = '' THEN
signal sqlstate '45000';
END IF;
END;$

INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos) VALUES ('', '');
```

Prueba de funcionamiento

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8c4eafb11e666c9f757955e0a6e4a0a

Comment: Hola @Edgar Vazquez, gracias por responder. Colocando el CHECK (nombre <> ''), no me evita que en estos campo se ingresen con datos vacíos, ¿Tienes alguna otra manera?

Comment: Podrias mostrarme como lo estas haciendo para tratar de replicar tu error

Comment: **Mil Gracias @Edgar Vasquez, con el disparador si funciono perfecto. Excelente tu ayuda Dios te Bendiga.**

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Si esta respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como correcta, para que otro que tenga el mismo error pueda verla, saludos :D